# Can't access broadcast variable from imported functions (PySpark)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, broadcast

First of all, my environment is as follows.

- AWS EMR : 6.1.0
- Spark : 3.0.0

**Case1 (Failure)** broadcast variable not accessible from an imported function

Let's say I have two scripts (a.py and b.py)

1. a.py

```
from b import do_something
⋮
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('HelpNeeded').getOrCreate()
data = {"name": "test"}
broadcast_variable = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(data)
df = ⋯
schema = ⋯
df.groupBy(["col_1","col_2"]).applyInPandas(do_something, schema=schema)
```

2. b.py

```
def do_something(df):
    ⋮
    data = broadcast_variable.value
    ⋮
```

If I run this with

```
$ zip src.zip b.py
$ spark-submit --deploy-mode client --py-files src.zip a.py
```

I get an error that says

```
broadcast_variable not defined
```

**Case2 (Success)** broadcast variable accessible from a function defined in the same file

1. a.py

```
def do_something(df):
    ⋮
    data = broadcast_variable.value
    ⋮

⋮
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('HelpNeeded').getOrCreate()
data = {"name": "test"}
broadcast_variable = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(data)
df = ⋯
schema = ⋯
df.groupBy(["col_1","col_2"]).applyInPandas(do_something, schema=schema)
```

And then if I run the script with

```
$ spark-submit --deploy-mode clinet a.py
```

I don't get any error meaning that broadcast_variable was properly accessed.

Anyone knows what I might have missed?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This simply won't work in Python. You need to pass the broadcast_variable to the function in b.py.

Comment: Hi @mck, if you say `This simply won't work in Python', does that imply it works with Scala and/or other languages? Plus, could you elaborate a bit more on why it doesn't work in Python? many thanks

Comment: it doesn't work because in b.py there is no such variable called broadcast_variable. broadcasting in spark means distributing the variable to the worker nodes, not between different scripts.